# Mock assertion types

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

In my main class, I have this code (this is the service, wants to work on any machine, not just where my work):

```
class MainClass:
    service = None
    key = None
    url = None

    def __init__(self, service, key, url, port):
        self.service = service
        self.key = key
        self.url = url
        self.port = port


def deleteMetod(self, room, params=None):

    try:
        if not isinstance(room, str) or (not isinstance(params, MainClass) and params != None):
            raise TypeError
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("Parameter 'room' should be a string. Parameter 'params' if there must be an instance of Nuve.")
    else:
        response = self.send('DELETE', None, '/rooms/'+room, params)
        return response
```

I want it to do a mock (MainClass) on this method in unit tests

```
def test_deleteMetodg_type(self):
    ob = MainClass("1212", "19414", "127.0.0.1", "3000")
    self.assertRaises(TypeError, ob.deleteMetod, [])
```

I want to make assertion and check if the return type of the method is correct.

but the object `Mock()` it is not possible assertion types only `assert_called_with()`

How do I mock the object and invoke its methods and compare the returned types?

Please for help/hint.

Comment: This question is simply "how do I use mock". There is extensive documentation: please read that, and come back with specific questions if you have any.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added details.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are hoping to mock here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added some details

Comment: You don't mock the object under test, that would be pointless: you'd then be testing your mock, not the actual code. You only mock any calls to external resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to test that your method raises a TypeError when provided incorrect arguments, then you don't have to mock anything.  Just call it (incorrectly), and assert that it raises the exception.

BTW, no need to raise then catch then raise the TypeError:

```
def deleteMetod(self, room, params=None):
    if not isinstance(room, str) or (not isinstance(params, MainClass) and params is not None):
        raise TypeError("Parameter 'room' should be a string. Parameter 'params' if there must be an instance of Nuve.")

    response = self.send('DELETE', None, '/rooms/'+room, params)
    return response
```

Also, in 2.7 and higher there is a more convenient assertRaises syntax:

```
def test_deleteMetodg_type(self):
    ob = MainClass("1212", "19414", "127.0.0.1", "3000")
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        ob.deleteMetod([])
```